# Part number of a connector in an Asus laptop

Tags: connector, identification, short-circuit, repair

While trying to repair a laptop, the connector linking the power button to the motherboard of a Asus x54h has burnt.

I am a software developer, I do not have very much knowledge in electronics, but I would like to repair that myself.

So I could change the connector, but I am afraid I may not have sufficient tools (just a basic soldering iron). 
I could also just wire pins which power on/off the laptop.

What is the name of the connector on the motherboard? And also what are the ways to repair the connection?

Some pictures:

[image: Photo 1 showing damaged connector]

[image: Photo 2 showing damaged connector]

Comment: Even if you could change that connector, the flat cable looks bad too, and should be replaced. Best bet would be to find the same computer and salvage the board/cable out of it. It's possible to remove/replace that connector with just a soldering iron, but it takes some skill not to burn the PCB. Also who knows what other damage is done further on in the board, I'm not sure how this happened but it looks like a LOT of current went through that connector/cable before it gave it's life for the cause...

Comment: Thank you. The computer seems to works well apart from that.

Comment: Yes the flat cable has to be changed too but I have already the reference (written on it)

Comment: I think you're looking for the *part number*, not the *reference number*. The reference number is the little number printed on the board next to the part, and has no relation to what actual part it is.

Comment: Yes, I have already this: J6601, if that helps. I am going to change the title of the question, thank you again.

Comment: I'm afraid the reference number doesn't actually help any. It's just the number the PCB designer gave to this particular part. Anyway, when trying to identify connectors, it's usually a good idea to compare to common JST and Molex parts to see what looks similar, then look at measurements and such.

Answer (score 3):

Look for 6 pins FPC/FFC connector and 6 contacts FFC/FPC cable (eBay, Aliexpress...) and try to find a connector that looks like the one you have burned.

You must first measure the contact pitch. It can be 0.5mm, 0.63mm, 1mm, 1.27mm, ...

You could repair it with a soldering iron and good eyes, but it must have, obviously, a very fine tip.
Maybe you should practice a bit soldering before hacking the laptop and, of course, disconnect the laptop battery.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer. The contact pitch is the distance between the two rows of pins on the connector, is that right ?

Comment: @Gaël Barbin. Yes, distance between centers of contacts. You should have the same pitch on the "SUMITOMO" flat cable and between pins on the connector.